# React Native video build failed

Tags: react-native

after i add react native video package to my project i could'nt build the project. my rn version is 0.60.3 i have installed latest version of react-native-video . the error is

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/C:/Users/avajang-pc/.m2/repository/com/android/support/support-media-compat/28.0.0/support-media-compat-28.0.0.pom
       - file:/C:/Users/avajang-pc/.m2/repository/com/android/support/support-media-compat/28.0.0/support-media-compat-28.0.0.jar
       - file:/C:/Users/avajang-pc/Desktop/newSpoc/spocplus/node_modules/react-native/android/com/android/support/support-media-compat/28.0.0/support-media-compat-28.0.0.pom
       - file:/C:/Users/avajang-pc/Desktop/newSpoc/spocplus/node_modules/react-native/android/com/android/support/support-media-compat/28.0.0/support-media-compat-28.0.0.jar
       - file:/C:/Users/avajang-pc/Desktop/newSpoc/spocplus/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/android/support/support-media-compat/28.0.0/support-media-compat-28.0.0.pom
       - file:/C:/Users/avajang-pc/Desktop/newSpoc/spocplus/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/android/support/support-media-compat/28.0.0/support-media-compat-28.0.0.jar
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/support-media-compat/28.0.0/support-media-compat-28.0.0.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/support-media-compat/28.0.0/support-media-compat-28.0.0.jar
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-media-compat/28.0.0/support-media-compat-28.0.0.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-media-compat/28.0.0/support-media-compat-28.0.0.jar
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-video
```

i've added maven , i changed the gradle version, build tools version.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command, react-native 0.60 now uses androidX and not all libraries are update to support it (one of them is react-native-video):

```
npm install --save-dev jetifier && npx jetify && react-native run-android
```

Comment: I got this error .   Failed to run jetifier. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: spawnSync C:\Users\avajang-pc\Desktop\newSpoc\spocplus\node_modules\jetifier\bin\jetify ENOENT

Comment: Try with `npx react-native run-android` if that doesn't work, remove node_modules, reinstall (via npm) and run npx as above again.